# Try catch nested in While Statement, clearing scanner

Tags: java, while-loop, nested, try-catch

So, I'm making a small program for school, and in the previous assignment we had to create a try catch finally statement to make the program not completely crash when it crashed, if that makes any sense...

and for this task that I'm working on now, this is not a demand, but I really want to find a proper way to do this, and so far I have created something a kin to the code below.

my problem lies with the fact that the scanner remembers what was written in the last input, so when someone writes something that crashes it and sets of the while loop again, the first question gets answered again..

So I'm sort of wondering if there is a way to "clear" the scanner before the program returns to the top of the code again?

I've found posts from people asking questions about this before, and they seem to get answers akin to "nope, that's not possible.."

but I guess there is a way to work around this?

I guess it could be the way I've set up the code and such..

Also, I will mention again that this is part of homework in my java class; sort of, the core program itself is, but the try catch part of this one, and especially restarting it isn't. but I'm always eager to learn more about this :)

**Example**

```
Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in)
Boolean abc = true;
String bucket;
int numbers = 0;

while(abc == true){
    abc = false;
    try{
        System.out.println("do you like me?")
        bucket = keys.nextLine(); *//user types in some string..*

        if(bucket.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            System.out.println("Yay! I love you too! :P");
        }
        else if(bucket.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            System.out.println("awww..");
        }

        System.out.println("How much money do you have on you?");
        numbers = keys.nextInt(); *//user types in **ex**. "no"*
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
    catch(Exception a){
        abc == true;
    }
    finally{
        if(abc == false){
            keys.close;
        }
    }
}
```

//when the user crashes the program by typing "no" in the int box, the program catches it and starts the while loop, and then it reads "no" as nothing took out this value from the scanner variable, and then the "do you like me" question gets answered automatically.. so if i had an "else" for anything not being yes or no, then that is what would be the automatic choice..

I really hope you guys(and girls?) might know something, or see a critical flaw in my logic that might fix this :)

Thank you for looking into and helping me with this! :D

Also as a sidenote question; do you know why people tend to use the "catch(Exception e)" with "e" as the "name" of the Exception? :) just curious..

Edit: So I figured out that I can just put in a String cleanUp; and then a cleanUp = keys.nextString(); in the catch block..

new question immediately arises: Should I do something about the warning the compiler gives me about the cleanUp value never being used? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need abc==true and if when no is typed you can just either break or you can make it  equals to false

```
while(abc){
    try{
        System.out.println("do you like me?")
        bucket = keys.nextLine(); *//user types in some string..*

        if(bucket.equals("yes")){
            System.out.println("Yay! I love you too! :P");
        }
        else {
           abc = false;
        }
        System.out.println("How much money do you have on you?");
        numbers = keys.nextInt(); *//user types in **ex**. "no"*
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
    catch(Exception a){
        abc == true;
    }
    finally{
        if(abc == false){
            keys.close;
        }
    }
}
```